# What goes into writing a cache simulator program?

Tags: c#, c++

Can any one explain or point me to a source that explain what goes into writing a cache simulator program.

It's a school project and I have no intention to use anyone else's code as it does me no good. I will be tested on understanding of the program and concept, but I would like so see some detailed material, a pseudo code or gant chart or something.

I'm asking here because text book and lectures have not given me enough information and I've googled for hours this week and found nothing relevant.

Comment: Have you considered going back to your teacher and explaining your situation? You have not demonstrated in anyway that you have researched this or have made any effort to learn more on your own.

Comment: What's a cache simulator?

Comment: Well @DanielKelley, I would be here asking if I have not. I had aske my teacher, he explained but and I thought I undersood, but not fully. Trully appreciate your downvote, NOT!!!

Comment: @Risho The fact Jacedc found 5 references through google kind of shows how simple it was.

Answer (score 3):

Try [this](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2012/cmsc411/p1/). But keep in mind about Academic Integrity, which is posted at the bottom of the page. It may not be the same school you go to, but I'm sure AI is universal regardless of whatever school assignment you're going through. You can also try [Googling your problem](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+write+a+cache+simulator+program&aq=f&oq=how+to+write+a+cache+simulator+program&aqs=chrome.0.57j62l2.6055j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), I found ~five references for doing so.

Comment: appreciate your time and effort. Like I said, I have no intention to use other code and/or plaigerize since as you know it's ealsy traceble for one, and I really need and/or want to understand the topic. Thanks!